# Find if an email is registered or not

Tags: python, email

Im new to stack overflow and i just signed up.

I have written a program to generate a random email. I need to see if this email is available, on icloud, gmail, and outlook. Is there a way to do this in python?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for [py3-validate-email 1.0.7](https://pypi.org/project/py3-validate-email/)

Comment: This would validate if the email format is valid but not verify if it actually exists or not.

Comment: @PrashanthTirupachur you should read the documentation: `check_smtp: check whether the email actually exists by initiating an SMTP conversation; defaults to True`

Comment: the package you recommended is a fork of github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email . The following are the issues mentioned: https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email/issues . Ref: 106, 109, 111, 112, 116, etc.. Both the parent repo and the forked repo mentioned aren't currently maintained and was last updated in 2015. Plus, not sure how safe it would be to use an un-maintained forked package.